# How to delete 1 history item from Chrome for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have tried the following:

Click History menu item > 
Show Full History >
Search for item speedtest.com >
Tick checkbox next to speedtest.com >
Click Remove Selected Item >
Restart Chrome

Now when I type speedtest into the chrome search bar I still get speedtest.com as the first item!?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0b3c8fb6931aac4c&hl=en) it says:

> You can delete single suggestions in the address bar . For Mac OS X 
>   Highlight the URL with your arrow keys and then SHIFT+FN+DELETE. At
>   least that has worked for me .

though it apparently only works when it feels to.

Comment: seems to work when there are multiple items.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work sometimes but not others; weird. Thanks @o0'.!

Comment: didn't work work for me. however, this did: CONTROL+FN+SHIFT+DELETE

Comment: If it doesn't work it could be because you have the entry bookmarked. This happened to me when I had a search entry bookmarked on Chrome on my iPhone and it was using the same google account I used on Desktop. I had to delete the bookmark from my iphone to get the search entry to dissappear.

Answer (score 3):

You must ensure that the item is not also in your bookmarks. Might seem obvious but yeah... if the entry is also in your bookmarks the attempt to `SHIFT+FN+DELETE` OR `SHIFT+CONTROL+FN+DELETE` will simply not work

Answer (score 1):

Simply highlighting the item in the URL and pushing `shift+fn+control+delete` works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With an external non-Apple keyboard (it has a Windows key) these steps worked for me:

Highlight the URL with your arrow keys and then Shift + Delete.

I guess the Fn from the other answers is only necessary for Apple keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press ⇧⌘A ( shift + command + A ) to search for related **tabs**
2. Hover each search result with your mouse cursor to reveal the close icon ×
3. Click each close icon × with your mouse to close the related tabs
4. Press ⌥⌘B ( option + command + B ) to search for related **bookmarks**
5. Click the menu icon ⋮ next to each related bookmark and select *Delete* from the menu
6. Press ⌘Y ( command + Y ) to search for related **history** entries
7. Check the checkbox ☑ next to each related item to reveal the *Delete* button
8. Click on the *Delete* button to delete related history entries
9. Press ⌘L ( command + L ) to move focus to the address bar
10. Use the autocomplete feature to verify that related items are no longer visible